# Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus: should I remove ProcessMessageAsync handler from ServiceBusProcessor on disposing?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am using [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus_7.5.0/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) library.

I create `ServiceBusClient` and `ServiceBusProcessor` to start receiving queue messages like this:

```
var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
ServiceBusProcessor processor = serviceBusClient.CreateProcessor(queue);
processor.ProcessMessageAsync += HandleEvent;
processor.StartProcessingAsync();
```

On application shutdown I dispose `ServiceBusClient` and `ServiceBusProcessor` in this way:

```
processor.ProcessMessageAsync -= HandleEvent; // Is this needed?
await processor.DisposeAsync();
await serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync();
```

Do I need to remove the `HandleEvent` explicitly, or `processor.DisposeAsync()` should be responsible for that?

I cannot find that `processor.DisposeAsync()` is removing any handlers in its code, however, probably it is because removing the handlers is not needed at all? Official documentation seems also lacking any good examples of how to dispose instances of `ServiceBusProcessor` properly.

Can it be that `await processor.DisposeAsync()` is not needed at all, since `serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync()` should do all the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it be that `await processor.DisposeAsync()` is not needed at all, since `serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync()` should do all the job?

Yes `await processor.DisposeAsync()` is not needed, because calling either `serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync()` or `CloseAsync` should do all the job and will  ensure that network resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.

And also  when a `ServiceBusClient` instance is **disposed**, it will automatically close and cleanup any senders, receivers, and **processors** that were created using it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Are you sure that `serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync()` will do all the job though? Probably I am missing something, but from [the code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus_7.5.0/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Client/ServiceBusClient.cs#L69) I see that `serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync()` does not dispose any processors. And it seems that processors do need to be disposed as well, since `ServiceBusProcessor` implements `IAsyncDisposable`.

Comment: yeah you can refer this MS document where it says about that -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme-pre#client-lifetime

Comment: This means I can delete explicit `processor.ProcessMessageAsync -= HandleEvent;` as well, cannot I?

Comment: yes! as this [says]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme-pre#client-lifetime
DisposeAsync() will do that job.