# How to make ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusProcessor DisposeAsync in BackgroundService class?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, .net-core-3.1, background-service

I have a class called 'TestService' which I use in a Windows Service to receive message from ServiceBus queue.

My question is how to make ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusProcessor dispose properly in Dispose() method as ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusProcessor use DisposeAsync()?

```
public class TestService : BackgroundService
{
    private ServiceBusClient _client;
    private ServiceBusProcessor _processor;

    public TestService ()
    {            
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _client = new ServiceBusClient("myConnection");
        _processor = _client.CreateProcessor("myQueue", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());
        _processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
        await _processor.StartProcessingAsync();
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _processor.StopProcessingAsync();            
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
         _processor.DisposeAsync(); //my question is here
         _client.DisposeAsync();    //and here
        base.Dispose();
    }

    private static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();

        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Hi, it is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```cs
public override void Dispose()
{
   _processor.DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
   _client.DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   /// [...]
}
```

But you should better think of implementing it with the `IAsyncDisposable` pattern described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable?view=net-6.0) or in the comment to this very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929083/azure-messaging-servicebus-should-i-remove-processmessageasync-handler-from-ser)

```cs
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
   await _processor.DisposeAsync(token); 
   await _client.DisposeAsync(token);
   /// [...]
}
```

Example from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/extensions/timer-service)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Are you saying the TestService should inherit from IHostedService, IAsyncDisposable then we have DisposeAsync?

Comment: @anhtv13 correct.

Comment: @anhtv13 did this solve your problem?

Comment: @Martin Will `DisposeAsync()` be called automatically by the dependency injection during shutdown? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#disposal-of-services) only talks about `Dipose()`. How would that issue be addressed by your `IAsyncDisposable` pattern solution?